# Echo something to console each time you quit crontab

Tags: cron, echo, stdout, output, nano

To edit the root crontab in Debian I do for example `sudo crontab -e`. To exit from the preferred text editor (*Nano*), I do `CTLR+X`.

So far so good, but what if I want that each time I exit crontab, a text will be echoed into the console (into "stdout").

The purpose is to `echo` a **reminder** message like:

> If you haven't already, change `p` to your password in `password[p]` to your password!

To make sure I'm clear here --- I desire that each time the user finished editing the crontab and then quited back to the console, the message will appear.

Is there any way to do so in the current release of Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the `$EDITOR` variable a script which first calls an editor and then produces the output:

```
#! /bin/bash

vim "$1"
echo "foo bar baz"
```

and use this call

```
EDITOR=/path/to/script.sh crontab -e
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a baf/ugly method for that .... Maybe someone have a better solution ...
replace crontab binary by a script  & rename original to somthing called crontab.original called by the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
crontab.original $1 #or all arguments if you wish to
echo YOUR MESSAGE
exit 0
```

Comment: Thx! What is `$1`?

Comment: 1st parameter $2 the second etc... in cas you wish to pass -l or -e options/args to crontab.original command

Comment: Oh I see, like `domain` for `${domain}` and then `example1.com`, `example2.com` and so forth, as execution arguments.

Comment: ho... I'm stupid ... a good way to do that would be to add a function in .bashrc or .profile like function crontab() { /usr/bin/crontab "$@" ; echo yourwarning ;}   without renaming the original ....    it is very better solution ..... $@ means all args ...and of course if you wish it to work immediatly just do : source .bashrc

Comment: @francoisP Shell functions don‘t work together with `sudo` :-)

Comment: Really ought to be `crontab.original "$@"` to be the least surprising behavior.